# Extracting posts of a facebook page into android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Is there a way to get the posts of a Facebook page(the page user has liked) every time the user requests?

I've seen lots of tutorials to share posts as status updates but couldn't figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [/page/feed endpoint documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed) that will fetch the posts by that page and by others on that page.

You can try it at [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) with a query like `cocacola/feed`.